# mounting an nfs share timeout on linux mint 14 client

Tags: mount, linux-mint, nfs

I am trying to mount an nfs share on a linux mint 14 (64bit).
I have already downloaded and installed `nfs-common` & `rpcbind` package in linux mint.
The server contains in `/etc/exports` the line

```
/nfs/lvm 192.168.112.0/24(rw,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
```

(the above export is a soft link to `/mnt/lvm`).

On the client side i type in the command line:

```
sudo mount stargaze:/nfs/lvm/ /mnt/lvm/
```

and I wait for a while but nothing happens.

at timeout I read in the client side: `mount.nfs: Connection timed out`
but there is nothing in `dmesg`!

I tested this share on another computer in my intranet, a slackware v14.0 32bit client and it mounts the share fine.

Am I forgetting something in Mint?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well it turns out, linux mint 14 was trying to connect to the share using nfs version 4.
I verified that enabling verbose output on the mount command of the client:

```
mount -v nfsserv:/nfs/lvm /mnt/lvm
```

It turns out slackware server wanted version 3 nfs preferably - or so it has been configured. So I tweak the command as follows:

```
mount -o vers=3 nfsserv:/nfs/lvm /mnt/lvm
```

and it mounted the share without a problem!

Comment: well -- search for basically an entire day for this. I thought it was something more severe. Thanks a lot for posting your soln.

Comment: @dylnmc no problem :)